# javascript image recognition script

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, image-recognition

I was wondering if there is a script or function in javascript which can recognize image patterns. I want to use this for automation. It is comparable to http://sikuli.org/ but I want this to run as a Firefox extension. I think https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/ has this functionality but not in the free version.

Answer (score 0):

As the Wikipedia article on [Computer Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) may suggest, this is a fairly large field within Computer Science.

While I haven't checked, I don't think there are any general-purpose scripts for the tasks you want to solve.

I suggest you read up on Computer Vision / Image recognition, and try to narrow down what functionality you're looking for, and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Hmm. I think basically I need some sort of hashing function to recognize if a certain picture is found. Sikuli does this nicely with a percentage you can define. For example if you define 100 % the found picture has to be an exact match. If you define 70% similarity there can be slight changes and so on ...